# Getting a compilation error for a simple program in serialization in java

Tags: java, file, serialization, stream

this is my Person class

```
package com.igate.serilaization;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Person implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Person(String name , int age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age= age;
    }


}
```

This is my main class

```
package com.igate.serilaization;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;


public class Serilalizer2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person p = new Person("Prasad", 18);

        try {
            FileInputStream fout = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/pmadge/Desktop/serial.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
            o.writeObject(p);
            o.close();
            System.out.println("Done");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

I am getting compilation error on `ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(fout); line like "The constructor ObjectOutputStream(FileInputStream) is undefined".

Comment: You probably meant to use `FileOutputStream`, not `FileInputStream`, right?

Comment: Yes i got my mistake , thanks @sstan it worked !

Answer (score 3):

you should use `FileOutputStream` instead `FileInputStream`

**Code**

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;


public class Serializer2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person p = new Person("Prasad", 18);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream ("C:/Users/pmadge/Desktop/serial.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
            o.writeObject(p);
            o.close();
            System.out.println("Done");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

I hope this helps you.